# Angular Universal ng-toolkit/universal setup issue

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal

`ng add @ng-toolkit/universal [bugsnag] Loaded! Skipping installation: Package already installed NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID`

I created a fresh new project in angular v16 and Local node -v 18.18

while tring to setup angular universal I am getting this issue   NOT SUPPORTED: keyword "id", use "$id" for schema ID`

Comment: any progress on that ?